# Count the different strings of one column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a situation where I have to count number of strings of different type in one column of a table, e.g. a column would have values such as :

```
apple
apple
apple
orange
orange
banana
banana
banana
banana
```

So I need to count the strings only of different type, that means query should give count result 3. What can be the ideal query for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count distinct values like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Getting result 1, im implementing on php, my code is `$query = mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT semail) FROM adpost");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);` @nes

Comment: doing echo `<?php echo $count; ?>`

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` returns row count of the query, you need the query_result itself, try `$a = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); print_r($a)`

Comment: Getting this `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Display.php on line 360
Array` @nes

Comment: Try this `$res = mysql_result($query, 0)`.

Comment: After this <?php print_r($count) ?> Getting `Array ( [COUNT(DISTINCT lower(semail))] => 18 )` 18 is correct what i am looking for but why displaying full query? @nes

Comment: yeahhhh... Done.. Thanks Brother... Can you explain why we take 0 in mysql_result() @nes

Answer (score 2):

So use `COUNT` with `DISTINCT` of string field `stringField` in your table `t`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT stringField) FROM t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT colmnname) FROM tablename
```

Comment: Getting result 1, im implementing on php, my code is `$query = mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT semail) FROM adpost"); $count = mysql_num_rows($query);` @Micallef

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using simple `COUNT(field)`, you could use `COUNT(DISTINCT field)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT fieldname) FROM tablename
```

If your values can have different upper/lower case variants and you still only want the real unique (e.g. `Banana` is the same as `banana`), then you can add `lower` function into the mix:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lower(fieldname)) FROM tablename
```

Comment: Sample with `lower()` needs clarification. It's needed only with collations, which are not `_CI` (i.e. case-insensitive). For example, default `latin1` isn't `_CI`, thus, `COUNT..DISTINCT` will treat `Banana` and `banana` as same strings

Comment: @AlmaDo Fair enough, although I think you meant the other way around.  `_CI` means `Banana` and `banana` are the same, but without `_CI` it will be.  `CI` really means 'case-insensitive'.

Comment: hm.. `ci` means "case-insensitive", right.. so? I mean that collation must not be ci (i.e. it must differ upper/lower cases)

Comment: @AlmaDo Nothing on top of that, I'm just saying that your point is valid.